# Issue running Google Lighthouse from PHP file

Tags: php, shell-exec, lighthouse

I have Lighthouse installed to run speed test scores for our websites ..  And it works, for me, user `zak`

I want to be able to run this from a php script ..  Here is the entire script.

```
<?php
if ( empty( $_POST['website'] ) ){
    die('Invalid Website');
}
echo shell_exec("whoami") . "<br />";
$website = $_POST['website'];
$test = shell_exec("npx lighthouse $website --chrome-flags='--headless'  2>&1");

echo "Test result for $website:<br />$test";
```

I get a return of:

> www-data
> Test result for exaple.com:
> npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

If I run that command native logged in as Zak:

```
$zak: npx lighthouse http://example.com --chrome-flags='--headless'  2>&1
```

It runs happily.

I made a bash script to test what `www-data` can see ..  And ran:

```
#!/bin/bash
node -v
nodejs -v
nmp -v
npx -v
which npx
```

Which returned

```
v16.16.0
v16.16.0
8.11.0
8.11.0
/usr/local/bin/npx
```

The super interesting part is, if I issue:

```
$zak: sudo -u www-data npx lighthouse http://example.com --chrome-flags='--headless'  2>&1
```

It runs command line!

So I know `www-data` can run `npx` and `node` commands just fine.  The error even indicates that it is *trying* to run it.  Why is `npx lighthouse` not running from my php file?  Is there special permissions I need to give it?  I cannot find any definitive documentation on this error.  Can I run further checks?  This seems like it might be a lighthouse bug?

**UPDATE**

After reading the verbose log:

```
33 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
33 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/index.js:24:3)
33 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
33 verbose stack     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
33 verbose stack     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
33 verbose stack     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12)
33 verbose stack     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:19)
33 verbose stack     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
33 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/exec.js:1:17)
33 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
33 verbose stack     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
```

The pertinent contents of `node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/index.js` is:

```
const { delimiter, dirname, resolve } = require('path')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const read = promisify(require('read'))

const Arborist = require('@npmcli/arborist')
const ciDetect = require('@npmcli/ci-detect')
const log = require('proc-log')
const npmlog = require('npmlog')
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp-infer-owner')
const npa = require('npm-package-arg')
const pacote = require('pacote')

const cacheInstallDir = require('./cache-install-dir.js')
const { fileExists, localFileExists } = require('./file-exists.js')
const getBinFromManifest = require('./get-bin-from-manifest.js')
const noTTY = require('./no-tty.js')
const runScript = require('./run-script.js')
const isWindows = require('./is-windows.js')
const _localManifest = Symbol('localManifest')

/* istanbul ignore next */
const PATH = (
  process.env.PATH || process.env.Path || process.env.path
).split(delimiter)  // <- ERROR
```

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, that is correct --  it is running as `www-data` as per the output of `whoami` -- Added to my question ..

Comment: You executed PHP command output, `"npx lighthouse $website --chrome-flags='--headless'  2>&1"`,  as yourself as well and it worked? I'm not seeing any `split` usage here.

Comment: I have done some more discovery .. But it raises more questions than answers ..   See my UPDATE ^

Answer (score 0):

Even though my ENV PATH was set for www-data:

```
$zak: sudo -u www-data printenv PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I had to include it into the command:

```
$test = shell_exec("export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin && npx lighthouse --verbose http://example.com --chrome-flags='--headless --no-sandbox'  2>&1");
```

The issue is that natively speaking `PHP` does not have access to even Apache's ENV set ..  It is turned off by default in the `php.ini`.  So if you `print_r($_ENV)` and see an empty array, most likely you need to uncomment the line that *allows* ENV in `php.ini` and you may need to set your `PATH` inside Apache, or PHP configuration.  I just figure it's easier setting the export path as a superglobal in my PHP application and call it that way.

```
$_GLOBALS['export_path'] = 'export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'

$test = shell_exec("$export_path && npx lighthouse --verbose http://example.com --chrome-flags='--headless --no-sandbox'  2>&1");
```

**UPDATE**

After reading [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) I found that the `$_SERVER` superglobal *contains* everything that `$_ENV` does.  And I printed out `echo $_SERVER['PATH'];` and viola .. There it was staring me in the face the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that I was not able to get an output from lighthouse when using it from PHP script. My PHP script looks very similar.

```
        $command = "sudo lighthouse --chrome-flags='--headless --no-sandbox' --quiet https://".$this->domain." --output=json 2>&1";
        $json = shell_exec($command);
        
        echo $json;
```

I solved the problem by adding the lighthouse command into the sudoers config. Using visudo command as root to edit sudoers and add

```
www-data        ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:    /usr/local/bin/lighthouse
```